# xbacklight not working on razer blade 2019

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, brightness, backlight

I'm trying and failing to get xbacklight to work on the Razer Blade 2019. The card is an Optimus Nvidia RTX 2080 max-q and the screen is a 4K OLED. I'm running 18.04 and using nvidia's proprietary driver 430.

Whenever I run `xbacklight -set ...`, there is no effect on the screen.

My `/sys/class/backlight` directory looks as follows:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
actual_brightness  bl_power  brightness  device  max_brightness  power  subsystem  type  uevent
```

But there is no change if I modify any of the files.

I have tried various kernel parameters that have been suggested here, but none have worked:

```
acpi_backlight=video
acpi_backlight=vendor
acpi_backlight=native
acpi_osi=Linux
acpi_osi="!Windows 2012"
acpi_osi=
video.use_bios_initial_backlight=0
video.use_native_backlight=1
i915.enable_dpcd_backlight
```

The only thing that works to modify the brightness is xrandx, but that doesn't actually affect the backlight

`xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --brightness .8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that it's an OLED screen and so doesn't employ a backlight. xrandr is the only way, but there is a script for it: https://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness

Comment: Yes, work well on Razer Studio RTX 5000. Thanks a lot @luke

Comment: A life changer was to install 19.10, which was much more stable for me and to use the latest nvidia drivers, which have optimus support.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted